# How to Attach HTTP Header while sending GET request

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I need to send a header along with http request and according to that header data gets processed at backened and then xml response comes from back-end side and that is made available to the UI side.My problem is that the back-end gets called 2 times one from ajax one and second after the success code.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: fileURL,
    headers: {
        'ItemCode1': array
    },
    type: "get",
    success: function(result) {
        var xmltext = result;
        var pom = document.createElement('a');
        var filename = "file.xml";
        var bb = new Blob([xmltext], {
            type: 'text/plain'
        });
        pom.setAttribute('href', window.URL.createObjectURL(bb));
        pom.setAttribute('download', filename);
        pom.dataset.downloadurl = ['text/plain', pom.download, pom.href].join(':');
        pom.draggable = true;
        pom.classList.add('dragout');
        pom.click();
    }
});
```

Comment: Please expand your question as I don't get what your getting at.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Your creating a JavaScript href to request another request? Nothing stopping you from create a mother Ajax request and amend the header? With href you cannot manipulate the header.

Comment: I one line could I make header to be called inside the success function ???